# Is there any way to make objects solids in Aframe?

Tags: aframe

I want to Make a scene so people can navigate through but they cant walk through objects.

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried before posting here.

Comment: <a-scene>
  <a-entity>
    <a-camera></a-camera>
  </a-entity>
  <a-box></a-box>
</a-scene>

Comment: I could solve this by ading:
<a-box static-body></a-box>